# Bar chart not showing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on the first set of D3 [tutorials](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-create-your-first-bar-chart-with-d3-js-a0e8ea2df386) and have a problem where the area of the SVG is shown but not any attributes of the `<rect>`s!

These are javascript, css and html sources!!

```js
var svgWidth =500;
var svgHeight = 300;

var svg = d3.select('svg')
.attr("width", svgWidth)
.attr("height", svgHeight)
.attr("class","bar-chart");

var dataset = [80,100,56,120,130,44,55,120,160];
var barPadding = 5;
var barWidth = (svgWidth/dataset.length);

var barChart = svg.selectAll("rect")
 .data(dataset)
 .enter()
 .append("rect")
 .attr("y",function(d){
  return svgHeight - d;
 })
 .attr("width", barWidth - barPadding)
 .attr("transform", function(d,i){
  var translate = [barWidth * i, 0];
  return "translate("+translate+")";
 });
```

```css
.bar-chart{
 background-color: #c7d9d9;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/index.css">
</head>
<body>
 <svg></svg>
</body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specified height -

```
.attr("height", function(d) {
        return d;
})
```

```js
var svgWidth =500;
var svgHeight = 300;

var svg = d3.select('svg')
.attr("width", svgWidth)
.attr("height", svgHeight)
.attr("class","bar-chart");

var dataset = [80, 100, 56, 120, 180, 30, 40, 120, 160];
var barPadding = 5;
var barWidth = (svgWidth/dataset.length);

var barChart = svg.selectAll("rect")
 .data(dataset)
 .enter()
 .append("rect")
 .attr("y",function(d){
  return svgHeight - d;
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return d;
    })
 .attr("width", barWidth - barPadding)
 .attr("transform", function(d,i){
  var translate = [barWidth * i, 0];
  return "translate("+translate+")";
 });
```

```css
.bar-chart{
 background-color: #c7d9d9;
}
```

```html
<svg></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Need to scale out the 'y-axis' of bar chart.**
Let's have a look on below code (see provided link as well)

```
var data = [80,100,56,120,130,44,55,120,160];

var width = 500,
    barHeight = 20,
    margin = 1;

var scale = d3.scale.linear().domain([10,1000]).range([50,500]);

var svg = d3.select("body")
              .append("svg")
              .attr("width", width)
              .attr("height", barHeight * data.length);

var g = svg.selectAll("g")
              .data(data)
              .enter()
              .append("g")
              .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
                  return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")";
              });

g.append("rect")
   .attr("width", function (d) {
       return scale(d);
   })
   .attr("height", barHeight - margin)

g.append("text")
   .attr("x", function (d) { return (scale(d)); })
   .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
   .attr("dy", ".35em")
   .text(function (d) { return d; });
```

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/d3js/scales-in-d3